# Require a class from /lib

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a class in `lib/utils.rb`. I figure I shouldn't autoload it, so I load it by demand:

```
require "/lib/utils"

class MyController < ApplicationController
```

But it's not getting found. I've tried different variations of the path but had no lack. What's up with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the `lib` directory of a RoR application is included in the Ruby's [`$LOAD_PATH`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Kernel.html#method-i-require), so you can require the `lib/utils.rb` file using `require 'utils'`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to to update your `require` statement as:

```
require "./lib/utils"
```

Wow! It works!